# How do you handle collection and storage of new data in an existing system?

Tags: database, database-design, architecture

I am new to system design and have been asked to solve a problem.

Given a car rental service website, I need to work on a new feature.

The company has come up with some more data that they would like to capture and analyze along with the data that they already have.

This new data can be something like time and cost to assemble a car.

I need to understand the following:

1: How should I approach the problem, from API design perspective?

2: Is changing the schema of your tables going to do any good, if that is an option?

3: Which databases can be used?

The values once stored can be changed. For example, the time to assemble can reduce or increase, hence the users should be able to update the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer you question let's divide it in two parts, ideal architecture and Q&A's

**Architecture:**

A typical system would consist of many technologies working together to solve a practical problem. Problems can be solved in many ways and may have more than one solution. We are not talking about efficiency and effectively of any  architecture here as it's whole new subject to explore. But it's always wise to choose what's best for your use case.

Since you already have existing software built, it's always helpful to follow it's existing design pattern which will help you understand existing code in detail and allow you to create logical blocks which will fit nicely and actually help in integrating functionality instead of working against it.

Since this clears the pre planning phase  let's discuss on how this affects what solution is ideal for your use case in my opinion.

**Q&A's**

**1. How should I approach the problem, from API design perspective?**

There will be lots of assumption, anything but less system consisting of api should have basic functionality of authentication and authorization when ever needed. Apart from that, try to stick to full REST specification, which will allow API consumers to follow standard paths and integration would have minimal impact when deciding what endpoints would look like and what they expect from consumer.

Regardless, not all systems are ideal for such use case and thus it's in up to system designer how much of system is compatible with standard practices.

Name convention matters when newer version api will have api/v2
    paths and old one having api/v1, which is good practice for routing
    new functionality. Which allows system to expand seamlessly.

**2: Is changing the schema of your tables going to do any good, if that is an option?**

In short term when you do not have much data, it's relatively easy to migrate data. When it becomes huge, it's much more painful and resource intensive.

Good practices would allow you to prevent such scenarios where you might not need migrate data.

Database normalization becomes so crucial in such cases when potential data structure would grow rapidly and requires attention.

Regardless of using any sql or nosql solution, a good data structure will always be helpful in both data management and programming implementation.

In my opinion, getting data structures near perfect is always a good
    idea, because it will reduce future costs of migration and
    frustration it brings. Still some use cases requires addition on
    columns and its okay to add them as long as it does not have much
    impact on existing code. Otherwise it can always be decoupled in
    separate table for additional fields.

**3: Which databases can be used?**

Typically any rdbms is enough for this kind of tasks. You might be surprised when you see case studies of large data creators still using mysql in clusters.

So answer is, as long as you have normal scenario, go ahead and pick any database of your choice, until you hit its single instance scalability limits. And those limits are pretty huge for small to mod scale apps.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I approach the problem, from API design perspective?

Design a good data model which is appropriate for the data it needs to store. The API design will follow from the data model.

> Is changing the schema of your tables going to do any good, if that is an option?

Does the new data belong in the existing tables? Then maybe you should store it there. Except: can you add new columns without breaking any existing applications? Maybe you can but the regression testing you'll need to undertake to prove it may be ruinous for your timelines. Separate tables are probably the safer option.

> Which databases can be used?

You're rather vague about the nature of the data you're working with, but it seems structured (*numbers?*). So that suggests a SQL with strong datatypes would be the best fit. Beyond that, use whatever data platform is currently being used. Any perceived benefits from a different product will be swept away by the complexities and hassle of deploying it.

Last word. Talk this over with your boss (or whoever set you this task). Don't rely on the opinions of some random stranger on the interwebs.